# jQuery show function prints to console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of displaying a div element after it has been hidden, the jQuery show() function printed the div element's html content on my browser's console.

html

```
<div id="fullAmountFail" class="alert alert-danger hide"></div>
```

javascript

```
$('#fullAmountFail').html(message);
$('#fullAmountFail').show();// this prints the var message in my broswer's console
```

Interestingly if I remove the .hide class from the div and hide it when the page loads with some javascript, the jQuery above works as expected. So, what up?

Comment: what is message?please share more

Comment: I assume you used the console to execute that js? In which case, because jQuery is chainable, it returns a reference to the div, which the console will output. Your problem is the definition of the `.hide` css.

Comment: @DvS No I didnt execute this in my console. it just printed there.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN message is a string

Comment: share the style rules for the hide class

Comment: @ArunPJohny Oh yes you make a point. It is a bootstrap class. Sorry for not mentioning this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `hide` class might be setting the `display` to `none` with `!important` override. The `show()` method sets inline style `display: block` which will get overriden by the `!important` notation

So just remove the hide class to display the element

```js
var message = 'some content';
$('#fullAmountFail').html(message);
$('#fullAmountFail').removeClass('hide');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullAmountFail" class="alert alert-danger hide"></div>
```

Comment: Ater going through bootstrap's css, you are right Arun. it uses none !important. very interesting piece of information. Thank you for the expertise